# How to disable delivery on certain date at checkout page in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using WooCommerce for my eCommerce website, I have added a custom checkout field "Delivery Date Picker" with the help of the official WooCommerce plugin "Checkout Field Editor" in my shipping field.

- Plugin Link: https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-checkout-field-editor/
- My Website: https://www.millionroses.com.au/
- [Checkout Field Date Picker Frontend Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3WXU.jpg)
- [Checkout Field Date Picker Backend Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGT2u.jpg)

There is no option in the Checkout field editor plugin backend to disable delivery on a particular date or holiday.

Suppose due to holiday; I want to disable delivery on 25,26 December or 1 January, then how can I disable delivery date on these particular dates?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using plugin, you need to override plugin functionality using hooks.
So, in your case, we need to override date picker functionality in your theme's `functions.php` file.

`unavailableDates` is a variable where you need to pass the dates that need to be disable and other functional code indicate that you need to destroy current date picker function and re-initiate the date picker function as per your requirement using `wp_footer` hook.

Below is the code snippet that i have created and it is fully  logical.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_footer_callback');
function wp_footer_callback(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).on('ready', function(){
        var unavailableDates = ["17-12-2019", "19-12-2019", "15-12-2019"];
        function unavailable(date) {
            dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
            if (jQuery.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
                return [true, ""];
            } else {
                return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
            }
        }
        jQuery(".checkout-date-picker").datepicker("destroy");
        jQuery(".checkout-date-picker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
            beforeShowDay: unavailable
        });

    });
</script>
<?php   
}
```

Let me know if it does not help.

Comment: Thank you so much, You saved my day :)